# Distributing an executable Jar console app

Tags: java, jar, console, distribution

(Using JDK7)

A friend of mine asked me to write him a program for rolling dice of arbitrary number and size. So I did. For simplicity's sake, I kept it as a console app. Now I'm trying to distribute it to him. I tried exporting it as a Runnable Jar with Eclipse's built-in exporter.

After opening it with Java (As opposed to javaw)... Nothing happens. I'm able to take a screenshot of the command prompt before it closes, and it reads:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\Roller.jar
```

Contents of Roller.jar

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
roller/Roller.class
```

Contents of MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:  . 
Main-Class: roller.Roller
```

Contents of Roller.java:

```
public class Roller{
/* Irrelevant code expunged */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Irrelevant code expunged
    }
}
```

I want to get this in a state where I can just email him the .jar and he can double-click it to run it. Can anyone help?

Comment: If it's a console app (or even if it weren't), you can actually run it on the console to get a more detailed error message.  Just open your platform's command line (`cmd` in Windows) and do `java -jar /path/to/Roller.jar`.  You'll no longer need to take a screenshot to see the error message.

Comment: @Matt G: "console app", "he can double-click it to run it" - I just created a class that makes that possible, it's only one additional call for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32547250/3500521

Answer (score 0):

In Roller.java, you need to add `package roller;` to the top of your class to match Roller.class being in the roller folder in the JAR file. After this, you don't even need to specify a Class-Path in your Manifest file.