# Sharing Java File, Mac alternative to .bat opening jar

Tags: java

I don't know anything about making GUI's in java. This is a simple text input program that I want to show to someone. Normally I'd package a compiled jar with a .bat file that has this code "java -jar project.jar".
And that would be all it takes. Problem is they're running a mac. I don't have a mac so I have no way to mess around and try to figure out how to make the jar open in terminal (I know you can just open terminal, navigate to where the jar is, and run it from there, problem is that they may get confused by that or not have the time, I'd rather them be able to open my project with a swift double-click, and explore it.) Is there any alternative to a .bat file, that is able to open a jar with just a click? If so, can you send me what I'd need to include in the file, ideally with a little instruction so I don't mess up, since I wont be able to test the file myself.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, jars can't open their own console.
I'd recommend you using a .sh file. It works almost the same as a .bat file. I can't help you here further cause I never programmed for or on a mac but the internet certainly does.

I also found this question:
[How to execute JAVA program by double clicking on icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338389/how-to-execute-java-program-by-double-clicking-on-icon/32547250#32547250)

Someone wrote a class to let the program run itself with a console. However, I don't know how well this works. I only tested it on windows.

And a third option would be to write your own console.